# EasyMapping - map array of strings in to CoreData and other questions

Tags: ios, json, core-data, mapping

1) Hello, i'm new in EasyMapping, i need to map array of strings to CoreData, key - "photos", how can i do this? In my xcdatamodeld i create key with NSData type i hope i can map array to NSData, or i can't? Or there are some other ways? Thank you!

```
{
     id: 262,
     title: 'Fort Hamilton',
     photos : [
                   'http://url//locations/47/photo/ab/db/eb/4d/2122/photo_2122.jpg',
                   'http://url//locations/47/photo/5a/1e/3a/5a/2123/photo_2123.jpg'
               ]
}
```

2) Can i map such JSON

```
{
street: 'bla',
city: 'bla bla',
coordinates:{
           lat : 12345,
           lon: 12345
       }
}
```

like this

```
+(EKManagedObjectMapping *)addressMapping {
    return [EKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Address class]) withBlock:^(EKManagedObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapPropertiesFromArray:@[@"street", @"city"]];
// i don't want to create new NSManagedObject to store my "lat" and "lon", can i do this trick?
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"coordinates.lat" toProperty:@"latitude"];
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"coordinates.lon" toProperty:@"longitude"];
   }];
}
```

3) Should i register my mappings or they register automatically?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked for existing solutions like restkit?

Comment: @Wain this lib much easier and pleasant to use then RestKit :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Example

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"photos" toProperty:@"photos" withValueBlock:^id(NSString *key, id value, NSManagedObjectContext *context) {
            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:value]];
            return data;
        }];
```

2) Yes

3) It need only in repo example, i can put mappings in `+(EKManagedObjectMapping *)objectMapping` method in my CoreData subclasses, see example in EasyMapping repo.